# Attempted import error: 'ApiRequests' is not exported from './ApiRequests'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in js and react,so:

i try to export js function:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { LazyLog } from 'react-lazylog';    
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Dropdown  } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {ApiRequests} from './ApiRequests'


var textConst="";
var lines=ApiRequests.GetMockLogLines();
textConst=lines;
```

And ApiRequests.js:

```
export function GetMockLogLines()
{
 let logs=[""]
 return logs;
}
```

So, when i compile js (o, my God) it breaks me:

```
Attempted import error: 'ApiRequests' is not exported from './ApiRequests'.
```

When i change it to :

```
 import ApiRequests from './ApiRequests'
```

->

```
 Attempted import error: './ApiRequests' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ApiRequests').
```

So, i just want to get function from another file. What i do wrong?

And what difference between {} and without it?  (you can send me a link  start to read,pls).

Comment: You’ve named the function `GetMockLogLines` so you have to import it with `import { GetMockLogLines } from './ApiRequests'`

Comment: You can also import it like this `import { * as ApiRequests } from './ApiRequests'`. But I think you need to think about what is the most appropriate way to structure your code in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function named Apirequests in your file. The function you are exporting is `GetMockLogLines()`

So your import should be

```
import {GetMockLogLines} from './ApiRequests'
```

As for the importing difference betweent {} and without the curly braces is how you are exporting your stuff from your file. There are two types of exports - Default export and named exports. One can have only one default export per file and it has to be imported without the curly braces.

You can read more here - https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Answer (score 1):

you need to import `GetMockLogLines` directly as it is a named import.
change your code to the following.

```js
import { GetMockLogLines } from './ApiRequests'
var lines=GetMockLogLines();
```